# Using Configurable Products in 1.8

Tags: configurable-product, magento-1.8

I upgraded to V 1.8, now I'm having problems with all my configurable products. I'm not able to remove the associated products, and I can't create new configurable products. When I try to create a new configurable product, it lets me go through the whole process, but when I save the product, it just goes back to not associating with the associated products.

I didn't get any errors when I upgraded to 1.8 nor am I getting any errors now, the system is just ignoring me.

Anyone have the same problem, or better yet, anyone with a solution to this problem?

Comment: I have the same issue when upgrading from 1.7.0.2 to 1.8.0.1 Have you found a fix for this yet? thanks

Answer (score 2):

I did find the answer here. http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/664565/ and here http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/616008/

I placed the links because I didn't want to take credit for other peoples answer. The error that happens when you upgrade from a previous version to 1.8 is that one file doesn't get updated, what you need to do is download the complete V1.8 file from MagentoCommerce, go to the JS folder, in there you'll see a folder named "scriptalicious", copy that folder into your backend and the problem should go away.

Comment: Feel free to mark it as accepted even if you dont want to take credit ;)